# Why are my balls fusing to my left and top wall when they bump into it? Ball collision program

Tags: java, swing, collision-detection, collision

I've created a ball collision program within Java, and it's working ok, but it's acting very weirdly. One problem I'm having is that the balls seem to fuse to the left wall and top wall, eventually all crunching up into the corner. I just want them to bounce off the walls and with each other. I'm pasting the code of my event handler. The event is every time my timer ticks, all balls within the array are checked for collisions. Any solutions?

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    tm.stop();
    for (Ball b:balls){


        if (b.getX()+b.getWidth()>this.width){
            b.setxSpeed(-(b.getxSpeed()));
            //b.setX(b.getWidth());
        }
        if (b.getX()<0){
                b.setxSpeed(-(b.getxSpeed()));
            b.setStuckCounter(b.getStuckCounter()+1);

            //b.setX(this.width-b.getWidth());
        }
        if (b.getY()<0){
                b.setySpeed(-b.getySpeed());
                //b.setStuckCounter(b.getStuckCounter()+1);
            //System.out.println(b.getStuckCounter());
            //System.out.println("X:"+b.getX()+" Y:"+b.getY());
            //b.setY(this.height-b.getWidth());
        }
        if (b.getY()+b.getWidth()>this.height){
           // b.setY(b.getWidth());
             b.setySpeed(-(b.getySpeed()));

        }
        if(b.getStuckCounter()==5){
            b.setxSpeed(1);
            b.setySpeed(1);
            b.setStuckCounter(0);
            System.out.println(b.getStuckCounter());
        }



       // b.xpos+=xSpeed;
       // b.ypos+=ySpeed;
        //b.setX(b.xpos);
        //b.setY(b.ypos);
        b.move(b.getxSpeed(),b.getySpeed());
        repaint();

        for (Ball c:balls ){
           /* double finalVelX1=((0.9*c.getMass()*(c.getxSpeed()-b.getxSpeed()))+(b.getMass()*b.getxSpeed())+((c.getMass()*c.getxSpeed()))/(b.getMass()+c.getMass()));
            double finalVelX2=((0.9*b.getMass()*(b.getxSpeed()-c.getxSpeed()))+(b.getMass()*b.getxSpeed())+((c.getMass()*c.getxSpeed()))/(b.getMass()+c.getMass()));
            double finalVelY1=((0.9*c.getMass()*(c.getySpeed()-b.getySpeed()))+(b.getMass()*b.getySpeed())+((c.getMass()*c.getySpeed()))/(b.getMass()+c.getMass()));
            double finalVelY2=((0.9*b.getMass()*(b.getySpeed()-c.getySpeed()))+(b.getMass()*b.getySpeed())+((c.getMass()*c.getySpeed()))/(b.getMass()+c.getMass()));*/ //Is equations for non-static collisoions

            double finalVelX1e=((b.getxSpeed()*(b.getMass()-c.getMass())+2*(c.getMass()*c.getxSpeed()))/(b.getMass()+c.getMass()));
            double finalVelX2e=((c.getxSpeed()*(c.getMass()-b.getMass())+2*(b.getMass()*b.getxSpeed()))/(b.getMass()+c.getMass()));
            double finalVelY1e=((b.getySpeed()*(b.getMass()-c.getMass())+2*(c.getMass()*c.getySpeed()))/(b.getMass()+c.getMass()));
            double finalVelY2e=((c.getySpeed()*(c.getMass()-b.getMass())+2*(b.getMass()*b.getySpeed()))/(b.getMass()+c.getMass()));


            if (c!=b && distance(b,c)<=b.getWidth() && elasticCollsions){

                if(distance(c,b)<=c.getWidth()){
                    /*double vx1=b.getxSpeed();
                    double vx2=c.getxSpeed();
                    double vy1=b.getySpeed();
                    double vy2=c.getySpeed();
                    double m1=b.getMass();
                    double m2=c.getMass();*/
                    b.setxSpeed(finalVelX1e);
                    c.setxSpeed(finalVelX2e);
                    b.setySpeed(finalVelY1e);
                    c.setySpeed(finalVelY2e);
                /*    if (finalVelX1 == finalVelX2 && finalVelY1 == finalVelY2){
                        b.setxSpeed(-finalVelX2);
                        b.setX(b.getX()-b.getWidth()/2);
                    }*/

                    b.move(b.getxSpeed(),b.getySpeed());
                    c.move(c.getxSpeed(),c.getySpeed());
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            else{

                if(distance(c,b)<c.getWidth() && !elasticCollsions){
                    /*double vx1=b.getxSpeed();
                    double vx2=c.getxSpeed();
                    double vy1=b.getySpeed();
                    double vy2=c.getySpeed();
                    double m1=b.getMass();
                    double m2=c.getMass();
                    double restitution=0.5*/
                    b.setxSpeed(finalVelX1e);
                    c.setxSpeed(finalVelX2e);
                    b.setySpeed(finalVelY1e);
                    c.setySpeed(finalVelY2e);
                /*    if (finalVelX1 == finalVelX2 && finalVelY1 == finalVelY2){
                        b.setxSpeed(-finalVelX2);
                        b.setX(b.getX()-b.getWidth()/2);
                    }*/

                    b.move(b.getxSpeed(),b.getySpeed());
                    c.move(c.getxSpeed(),c.getySpeed());
                    repaint();
                }

            }

        }
    }
    tm.start();


}
```

the 'for (Ball c:Balls)' loop is used to detect colliding balls.
Edit: The balls have mass and I use equations to calculate their speed and velocity after colliding

Comment: Typically this happens when your ball is going so fast that `b.move(b.getxSpeed(),b.getySpeed())` causes the ball to become partially lodged in the wall before the collision check happens. I'm guessing this only happens at high speeds?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @jamie You should note that at high speed or low frame rates you might have a collision degenrate situation known as *tunneling*. If due to tunneling, any ball gets *inside* a wall, your code won't fix it.